# How do I format a Decimal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to format a decimal like this:

```
00.33
11.24
05.22
```

The problem is that when I retrieve `00.33` it outputs as `0.33`.

I tried everything and can't get it to work correctly. I could do MySQL's `Zerofill` but I'm really trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sprintf("%05.2f", 0.33)
# or
"%05.2f" % 0.33
```

Comment: Docs: [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf). The width is optional, eg. format dollars and cents with `%.2f`

Answer (score 3):

Use printf to format the float as follows:

```
printf( "%05.2f", yourFloat)
```

For `printf` examples in C++ see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/.

The Ruby docs for `sprintf` are at: [http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/function.html#sprintf**).